# Is it possible to load imagick extension in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, imagick

My web host told me that I can install imagick but cannot alter php.ini but can turn on imagick in `.htaccess`. Is this true? How would I load it in htaccess?

**php.ini syntax**

```
#Syntax in php.ini
extension=imagick.so
```

What's the syntax for loading it in htaccess files?

(This is linux - I think it's Fedora)

Comment: Who is your web host?

Comment: @totallytotallyamazing 1and1

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](http://return-true.com/2009/02/installing-imagemagick-imagick-php-extension-on-dreamhost/) for one solution that includes the following .htaccess info.

Adding this to your .htaccess file is part of the process:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler php-cgi .php
Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php.cgi

<FilesMatch "^php5?\.(ini|cgi)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
</FilesMatch>
```

Also try this http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/php-cgi-redirect_status.html

and this http://search.cpan.org/~grichter/Apache-ImageMagick-2.0b7/ImageMagick.pm

Please let me know if any of these are a help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load the extension in your php script via http://php.net/dl

Comment: Doesn't that require knowing the extensions directory and hardcoding it?

Comment: No full path required because php knows where to look for extensions. But indeed you need to know if you are on linux or windows. Because your file extension is either .so or .dll respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for non-root userswould be to use a custom php.ini, which can be done several different ways:  http://www.askapache.com/php/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html